# In tensorflow How could I get the min value index but except zero

Tags: tensorflow

I want to get the min value index of a tensor, but the value is not 0.

```
a = np.array([[0, 3, 9, 0],
            [0, 0, 5, 7]])
tensor_a = tf.constant(a, dtype=tf.int32)
max_index = tf.argmax(tensor_a, axis=1)
```

The above code defined a constant tensor, if I use tf.argmax, I will get the index [2, 3]. How could I get the index of 3 in row one and 5 in row two, the min value but not zero. The true indexes I want to get is [1, 2].
How to implement it in tensorflow, Thanks.

Comment: What are you looking for? The maximum values are 9 and 5 respectively, at indices 2 and 3. What are you looking for?

Comment: I want to get the minimum values indices except  zero. How could I get the minimum  value's index in tensor_a (0 should be exclueded). In the above example, because I don't need 0, so the minimum value in row 1 is 3, the minimum value in row 2 is 5. The code should return [1, 2].

Comment: Something like `tf.min(tf.boolean_mask(x > 0))` perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

It's hideous, but it works:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    a = np.array([[0, 3, 9, 0],
                [0, 0, 5, 7]])
    tensor_a = tf.constant(a, dtype=tf.int64)
    row_max = tf.reshape(tf.reduce_max(a, axis=-1), [-1, 1]) + 1
    max_index = tf.argmin(tf.where(tensor_a > 0, tensor_a, row_max * tf.ones_like(tensor_a)), axis=1)
    print(max_index.eval()) # -> [1 2]
```